# Ruby on Rails on Digital Ocean Nginx Unicorn Page not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, centos, unicorn, digital-ocean

UPDATE: I give up installing by myself and use the 1-click rails app and it's works fine.

I follow the instructions [How To Deploy Rails Apps Using Unicorn And Nginx on CentOS 6.5](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-rails-apps-using-unicorn-and-nginx-on-centos-6-5) and build the exact app (my_app). The only change I made is include unicorn in the Gemfile.Both nginx and unicorn are running fine.

When only the ip address `http://107.170.197.55/` the nginx page shows up. However when I run ip with tasks (`http://107.170.197.55/tasks`) it shows up "The page you are looking for is not found". Here's the code. Let me know if you need more information.

Is it because I am using CentOS 7?

/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

```
upstream app {
# Path to Unicorn SOCK file, as defined previously
server unix:/tmp/unicorn.myapp.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
listen 80;
server_name localhost;

# Application root, as defined previously
root /root/my_app/public;

try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

location @app {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://app;
}

error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
client_max_body_size 4G;
keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

/var/www/my_app/config

```
# Set the working application directory
# working_directory "/path/to/your/app"
working_directory "/var/www/my_app"

# Unicorn PID file location
# pid "/path/to/pids/unicorn.pid"
pid "/var/www/my_app/pids/unicorn.pid"

# Path to logs
# stderr_path "/path/to/log/unicorn.log"
# stdout_path "/path/to/log/unicorn.log"
stderr_path "/var/www/my_app/log/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "/var/www/my_app/log/unicorn.log"

# Unicorn socket
listen "/tmp/unicorn.myapp.sock"

# Number of processes
# worker_processes 4
worker_processes 2

# Time-out
timeout 30
```

Comment: who performs request to `/tasks`?

Comment: I set my root as `root tasks#index`. Don't know if that answer your question.

Comment: you have to verify your production logs in rails app

Comment: I only have one log in my production log `Migrating to CreateTasks` Seems like there should be more right?

Comment: yes, that should be more, because it seem  that **all** the requests don't reach the rails app.

Comment: I don't know what happened...I'm fairly new to VPS kind of stuff. I put it on Github can you help me take a look at it? thanks https://github.com/CocoHot/my_app

Comment: and what is in the `/var/www/my_app/log/unicorn.log`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66902/discussion-between-cocohot-and--).